# Poincaré Inequality - Requirements/Proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We had the following version of the Poincaré Inequality:

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open st $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times (a, a+d)$ for an $ a \in \mathbb{R}, d>0$. Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Then $|| f|| _{L^p (\Omega)} \leq d || \nabla f ||_{L^p(\Omega)}$ for all $f \in W^1_{p,0}(\Omega)$.

**First Question:** I've read that without the requirement $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times (a, a+d)$, the statement is in general wrong. Why? Of course, we use this in the proof but I don't see why it is strictly necessary.

**Second Question:** In the proof, we had the following inequality:

$$|f(x)| \leq ||1|| _{L^{p'} ((0,d))} \cdot || \partial_{x_n} f(x',.)|| _{L^p ((0,d))}.$$ Then, we use $$|| ~||\partial_{x_n} f(x',.)|| _{L^p ((0,d))}||_{L^p (\Omega)}  \leq ||1||_{L^p ((0,d))} \cdot ||\partial_{x_n} f(x',.)|| _{L^p (\Omega)} ~~~*$$
which gives 
$$ ||f||_{L^p (\Omega)} \leq d ||\partial_{x_n} f(x',.)|| _{L^p (\Omega)}~~ **$$
which then implies the claim. I don't see why * holds nor do I understand how I get the claim from ** .

Thank you very much for your explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Question**

Suppose $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\psi \in W^{1}_{p,0}$ be any function (but you can imagine for example that $\psi$ is a Gaussian).  Define the functions
$$
\psi_R(x) = \psi(x/R).
$$
Observe that $\|\psi_R\|_{L^p} = R^{d/p}\|\psi\|_{L^p}$ and $\|\nabla \psi_R\|_{L^p} = R^{d/p-1}\|\nabla\psi\|_{L^p}$.  Thus the ratio
$$
\frac{\|\psi_R\|_{L^p}}{ \|\nabla\psi_R\|_{L^p}} \to \infty
$$
as $R\to\infty$.  This contradicts any Poincare inequality one could have hoped for.

**Second Question**
Let's first work with $\ast$.  Observe that 
$$
\int_{\Omega} \int_0^d |\partial_{x_n} f(x',s)|^p\,ds \,dx
= \int_0^d \left(\int_{\Omega'} \int_0^d |\partial_{x_n} f(x',s)|^p\,ds\,dx'\right)\,dt.
$$
But the term in parentheses is just $\|\partial_{x_n} f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^p$.  Thus 
$$
\int_{\Omega} \int_0^d |\partial_{x_n} f(x',s)|^p\,ds \,dx
= d \|\partial_{x_n} f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^p.
$$
Now $\ast$ follows by raising both sides to the $1/p$.

The claim follows from $\ast\ast$ because $|\partial_{x_n} f| \leq |\nabla f|$.

Answer (score 1):

**Ad 1.** There is a good reason for this. Assume that for some $p,q \in [1, \infty)$ there is an inequality of the form 
\begin{equation}
\label{poincare}
\| f \|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le C(n,p,q) \| \nabla f \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}
valid for all functions $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The version you are proving is for $p=q$, but works only if $\operatorname{supp} f$ is contained in a strip.

Fix some non-zero $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and consider the family of functions $f_t(x) = f(tx)$ for $t > 0$. Calculating the ratio $\| f \|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^n)} / \| \nabla f \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ as a function of $t$ and using the fact that this ratio is uniformly bounded, we get $q = \frac{np}{n-p} > p$.

Indeed, for this particular value of $q$ this inequality is known to be true (under the name Sobolev-Poincare).

Taking a closer look at this reasoning for $q=p$, we can notice that the ratio $\| f \|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^n)} / \| \nabla f \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ blows up when $t \to 0$, i.e. when the support gets larger and larger. Therefore, the assumption that $\operatorname{supp} f$ is contained in a strip (or some other additional assumption) is needed.

---

**Ad 2.** It seems to me that your confusion comes in part from using $L^p$ norms everywhere. If you're not familiar enough with it (yet), I'd suggest writing down the proof for $p=1$ using integrals, which should be fairly easy. Then the case $p>1$ can be obtained by Holder's inequality.